# Moment of inertia of a rod, what is wrong?

Tags: moment-of-inertia

The moment of inertia (MOI) of a rod that rotates around its center is $\frac{1}{12} m l^2$, while a rod that rotates around its end is $\frac{1}{3} ml^2$, as listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia).

That doesn't sound right - please see the image. A rod that rotates around its center can be viewed as two rods rotating around a common end point. Each rod's MOI is $\frac{1}{3} ml^2$, so two rods have MOI $\frac{2}{3} ml^2$

What is wrong?[image]

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99573/392

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Start with the moment of inertia (about one end) of a rod of length $L/2$ and mass $m/2$:

$$ I = \frac{1}{3}\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^2  = \frac{mL^2}{24} $$

Multiply by two, to get a rod of length $L$ and mass $m$ pivoted about the middle and you get:

$$ I = \frac{mL^2}{12} $$

You forgot to allow for the doubling/halving of the mass.

Answer (score 5):

The rod is characterised by a constant linear mass density $\lambda$, whence $I = \frac1{12}\lambda L^3$ for the one rotating around its centre. Take two rods of length $L/2$ to get $2\frac13\lambda(L/2)^3 = \frac1{12}\lambda L^3$.