# Good Source to Understand Angular Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, resource-recommendations, rigid-body-dynamics

I am looking for a good source to understand angular momentum. I know the basics but I am looking for a sound in-depth knowledge like directions of angular momentum, when it is not parallel to angular velocity, differences between normal angular momentum and spin angular momentum, how one is intrinsic property and other is not, etc.

Can you please help? Any book, any video, any website etc.?

Comment: What's your education level? Are you just trying to learn it on your own or do your find your textbooks lacking and want another source? etc

Comment: Halliday & Resnick.   or Kahn Academy.

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88566/392

Comment: What's the problem with Goldstein, Landau, Saletan and other classical mechanics books?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic in that it does not specify enough objective criteria, as per our [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698).